# Extending Prolog predicates

Tags: prolog

I have prolog predicates `male, female, parent`, as follows:

```
parent(bob, rick).
parent(jane, rick).
parent(rick, alice).
parent(betsy, alice).
male(rick).
female(jane).
```

Now, one way to infer incomplete gender info is to see if one parent is male, then the other has to be a female and vice versa, so I tried to extend female:

```
female(X) :- parent(X, Y), parent(Z, Y), male(Z).
```

Thus, my final `female` predicate is:

```
female(jane).
female(X) :- parent(X, Y), parent(Z, Y), male(Z).
```

However, when I try:

```
?- female(jane).
true ;
false.

?- female(betsy).
true ;
false.
```

Why's the false coming up there? Further problems are arising when I try to do a similar thing for `male`, because that's leading to an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at what happens if you query female/1:

```
?- female(jane).
```

Prolog tries to prove the predicate by trying all facts and rules you have written for it. First the fact `female(jane).` matches successfully and Prolog tells you:

```
?- female(jane).
true
```

After you hit the `;`-key Prolog looks for further solutions:

```
?- female(jane).
true ;
```

There are no more facts for female/1 but a rule, so Prolog tries to prove the rule by proving its goals in the order you have written them. The `X` in the head of the rule is unified with `jane`. The first goal `parent(jane,Y)` succeeds for `Y=rick`. Then Prolog is trying to prove `parent(Z,rick)` which succeeds for `Z=bob`. Now Prolog tries to prove `male(bob)` but fails since your facts do not include `male(bob)`. So Prolog backtracks to the previous goal `parent(Z,rick)` and finds a second solution `Z=jane` (after all your rule does not specify that `X` and `Z` have to be different). However, the goal `male(jane)` fails. Prolog is backtracking to the previous goal but does not find any more solutions to `parent(Z,rick)` so it backtracks further to the first goal `parent(jane,Y)`.
 Since there are no more solutions to that either Prolog tells you:

```
?- female(jane).
true ;
false
```

To further illustrate how this works, I suggest you add a fact:

```
male(bob).
```

Now the query yields:

```
?- female(jane).
true ;
true ;
false.
```

Now follow the reasoning described above: The first `true` is because of the fact `female(jane)`. The second `true` you get because the rule succeeds since Prolog can prove `male(bob)` now. And the `false` you get because there are no more solutions.

The answers to your second query can be explained the same way: You get the answer `true` because `male(rick)` can be proved in the rule. The `false` tells you there are no more solutions.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I was confused because `true; false` seemed to be stating that `jane` is a female by one logic and not female by another, which should not be. Now I understand that it means that it means there are no more solutions. And good catch about me forgetting the `X \== Z` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anybody, I want to further add that in such a situation, if I also wanted to extend `male` similarly, it leads to an infinite recursion because `male` references `female` and `female` references `male`.

To avoid this, it is better to separate the facts and rules, like so:

```
male(rick).
is_male(X) :- male(X).
is_male(X) :- parent(X, Y), parent(Z, Y), X \== Z, female(Z).

female(jane).
is_female(X) :- female(X).
is_female(X) :- parent(X, Y), parent(Z, Y), X \== Z, male(Z).
```

(This is only appropriate here because further levels of recursion would not yield any extra info, which may not be true for other situations).

Comment: Be cautious when using the built-in \==/2. Consider the following queries: `?- X=Y, X\==Y.` yields `no` as expected but `?- X\==Y, X=Y.` succeeds with `X = Y` because \==/2 has no effect whatsoever on the variables so they can be subsequently unified. Consider using dif/2 instead if it's available in your Prolog-system. This way the aforementioned queries both fail: `?- X=Y, dif(X,Y).` yields `no` and `?- dif(X,Y), X=Y.` yields `no` as well.